# Using if condition with a combination of time duration and a specific value

Tags: python

I have a dynamic variable **temp_x**, whose value keeps changing. I want to have a if condition which executes after a specific duration of time is passed and at the specific value of **temp_x**

```
import time
while True: 
    temp_y.ValueConverted = 1
    time.sleep(20)
    if temp_x == 0:
        temp_y.ValueConverted = 3
        break 
print ('Done')
```

I couldn't figure out how to implement the waiting of 20 secs inside if conditon. So I put it outside. So I am trying to include the the 20sec waiting time into the if conditon.

Note: It can be that after the 20sec has passed, the value of temp_x might not be '0'. It has to wait until it touches '0', then execute the if statement. So basically the algorithm should first wait 20sec, then wait until the value of the temp_x is '0', then execute the if statement.

I am pretty sure I am doing wrong. If anyone could direct me into the right direction. It'd be great.

Edit 1:

```
while True: 
  temp_x.ValueConverted = 1
  time.sleep(20)
  while temp_y.VaueConverted != 0:
    temp_x.ValueConverted = 3
    break
```

The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users......\Experiment_001\Python Scripts\Script11211.py", line 66, in 
    while temp_x.VaueConverted != 0:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 530, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self.*username*, attr))
AttributeError: .VaueConverted

Comment: Try adding a "start_date" outside of the while loop and comparing to it in the if condition ;-)

Comment: Since you are waiting your static 20 seconds in the while loop but then need to wait until temp_x == 0, use another while loop after your sleep to wait until temp_x == 0

Comment: Do you really want to do it that way? Instead, you could make your variable implement an observer-pattern.

Comment: @NicoAlbers. That was my first thought as well. But I thought there should be a cleaner and easier way.

Comment: @RyanWilson. Check the edit. I did implement this before. But I am getting the error when it enters the 2nd loop

Comment: @Jack on your edit, you are waiting on temp_y to equal 0, I thought you wanted to wait for temp_x to equal 0

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with your code other than it was a bit more convoluted than it had to. The following looks more *on-the-money* to me:

```
import time

temp_y.ValueConverted = 1  # initial value
while temp_x != 0:         # until it becomes 0 we...
    time.sleep(20)         # ...wait
temp_y.ValueConverted = 3  # and then we update the original temp_y
print('Done')
```

Finally, note that we are blocking execution with our `while` block so the initial `temp_y.ValueConverted` value does not have any effect. We could skip initialization and define it **after** our check is fulfilled.

Comment: I don't think from his post that his loop should sleep 20 seconds each iteration, from what he posted it sounds as if it is to wait 20 seconds one time, then wait until temp_x == 0

Comment: As soon as the temp_y value is made 1. temp_x value can be 0. I need to consider the temp_x value only after 20sec. like @RyanWilson stated, time would be the first condition.